# solution for my code

Tags: php

> Notice: Undefined index: produk_id_terakhir in
>   E:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\load_data.php on line 5
>
> Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in E:\xampp\htdocs\bootstrap\load_data.php on line 7

this load_more.php

```
 <?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "rumahta_app");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produk LIMIT 2";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
$produk_id = '';
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Load More</title>
        <link href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div class="table-responsive">
                <table class="table table-bordered" id="load_more">
                <?php 
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
                {
                ?>
                 <tr>   
                    <td><?php echo $row["nama_produk"]; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $produk_id = $row["produk_id"]; 
                }
                ?>
                <tr id="remove_row">
                    <td><button name="btn_more" type="button" id="btn_more" data-vid="<?php echo $produk_id; ?>" class="btn btn-success form-control">More</button></td>
                </tr>
           </table>
          </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','#btn_more', function(){
            var produk_id_terakhir = $(this).data("vid");
            $('##btn_more').html("Loading...");
            $.ajax({
                url:"load_data.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:{produk_id_terakhir:last_produk_id_terakhir},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data)
                {
                    if(data != '')
                    {
                        $('#remove_row').remove();
                        $('#load_more').append(data);
                    }else{
                        $('btn_more').html("No Data");
                    } 
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

and this load_data.php

```
<?php
$connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "");
$output = '';
$produk_id = '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM produk WHERE produk_id > " .$_POST["produk_id_terakhir"]." LIMIT 2";
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
        $produk_id = $row["produk_id"];
        $output .= '
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td> '.$row['nama_produk'].' </td>
            </tr>
            </tbody> 
        ';
    }
    $output .='
            <tbody><tr id="remove_row">
                <button name="btn_more" type="button" id="btn_more" data-vid="'. $produk_id .'" class="btn btn-success form-control">More</button>
            </tr></tbody>
        ';
        echo $output;
}
?>
```

Comment: try echoeing the query and running it in db

Answer (score 1):

replace line 4 with this:

```
if (isset ($_POST["produk_id_terakhir"])) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM produk WHERE produk_id > " .mysqli_real_escape_string ($_POST["produk_id_terakhir"])." LIMIT 2";
} else {
    // to do: exit() or print error message
}
```